# Am I increasing dynamic range by increasing the bit rate of video?

Tags: bitrate

My smartphone allows me to change bit rate. Will I increase the dynamic range by doing that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't increase dynamic range *per se* like using a 10-bit encoder would, but it will throw out less information in shadows and highlights when it compresses, so the extremes of the dynamic range will look better.

Comment: Thank you! Now the question is, will extra image data from highhilights and shadows make noticeable difference in processed video ?! ... I mean: I record fottage in 100mbps, but once I upload on youtube, it will have like 40mbps in best case. Will I loose these extra image informations once youtube applies it's compression again ?

Comment: The better the input, the better the output, to some extent. The biggest difference is probably when you go to grade the footage, more detail in shadows and highlights will mean that you have more latitude to be able to tweak the exposure and look.